# layout widget for a sliding side menu for Android how to

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu

i want to Custom menu with sliding side but I do not understand how to use it.

i use slide menu for  https://github.com/lemonade-hq/SlideSideMenu

code activity_main.xml for me

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="app.mes.MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
            android:layout_below="@id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <com.app.mes.views.CustomSwipeRefresh
                                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                                <ViewStub
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/view_stub"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                            </app.mes.views.CustomSwipeRefresh>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
            android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:ntb_bg_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:ntb_inactive_color="@android:color/white"
            app:ntb_badge_position="right"
            app:ntb_badged="true"
            app:ntb_scaled="true"
            app:ntb_tinted="true"
            app:ntb_title_mode="all"
            app:ntb_titled="true"
            app:ntb_swiped="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

code for https://github.com/munday/sliding-menu

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.lemonade.widgets.slidesidemenu.SlideSideMenuTransitionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slide_side_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Item 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Item 2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Item 3"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Item 4"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.lemonade.widgets.slidesidemenu.SlideSideMenuContentCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <!-- Optional: Tool Bar -->
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/base_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        </FrameLayout>
    </com.lemonade.widgets.slidesidemenu.SlideSideMenuContentCardView>
</com.lemonade.widgets.slidesidemenu.SlideSideMenuTransitionLayout>
```

How can I use it?

Thank you I just started learning android.

Answer (score 0):

i use modify code not working run App Has Stopped

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/slide_side_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#fff"
tools:context="app.mes..MainActivity"
android:gravity="center">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.app.mes..views.CustomSwipeRefresh
                            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                            <ViewStub
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/view_stub"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                        </com.app.mes.views.NCCustomSwipeRefresh>
                    </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
        android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:ntb_bg_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:ntb_inactive_color="@android:color/white"
        app:ntb_badge_position="right"
        app:ntb_badged="true"
        app:ntb_scaled="true"
        app:ntb_tinted="true"
        app:ntb_title_mode="all"
        app:ntb_titled="true"
        app:ntb_swiped="true"/>
```